# Taking multiple locks within nested loops in cases where order cannot be anticipated

Tags: c++, thread-safety, locking

I have a graph of cross-referenced objects holding data that needs to be synchronized, and there are several threads applying "exploratory operations" over the graph.

This takes me to a situation where threads need to take the lock of a node to explore connected nodes and subsequently take theirs locks.

Is there a recommended way of doing this? without risking invalidating loops and applying deadlock avoidance?

Here is a minimal example of this with my initial approach, *exploratory_operation* shows the dilemma:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Node {

    public:

        Node(const T& data) : data_(data)
        {}

        void addNode(const std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>& node)
        {
            // Connects to a new node safely holding a unique lock
            std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutex);
            unsafe_addNode(node);
        }

        void unsafe_addNode(const std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>& node)
        {
            connections_.push_back(node);
        }

        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> getNodes()
        {
            // Returns a copy of connections safely holding a shared lock
            std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutex);
            return unsafe_getNodes();
        }

        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>& unsafe_getNodes()
        {
            return connections_;
        }

        T getData()
        {
            // Makes a copy safely holding a shared lock
            std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutex);
            return unsafe_getData();
        }

        T& unsafe_getData()
        {
            return data_;
        }

        mutable std::shared_mutex mutex;

    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> connections_;

        T data_;
};

void exploratory_operation(const std::shared_ptr<Node<int>>& node)
{
    /* 
        * Suppose that you cannot anticipate connections and that may exist
        * several other threads doing operations over nodes in aleatory order
        */

    // Taking node lock to read connections and execute unsafe functions
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(node->mutex);

    // We don't want to copy the entire set of connections using getNodes()
    for(const auto& other_node : node->unsafe_getNodes())
    {
        std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> other_lock(other_node->mutex, std::defer_lock);

        // Unlocking first as otherwise std::lock is UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR (lock is already taken)
        lock.unlock();
        // The for-loop may become invalidated in between (some another thread may add nodes and trigger vector's reallocation)
        std::lock(lock, other_lock); // Attempt locking with deadlock-avoidance

        for(const auto& other_other_node : other_node->unsafe_getNodes())
        {
            // These problems escalate on subsequent nested loops
            std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> other_other_lock(other_other_node->mutex, std::defer_lock);

            lock.unlock(); // to not get UB
            other_lock.unlock();

            std::lock(lock, other_lock, other_other_lock); // deadlock-avoidance

            // Working with data...
            std::cout << "Datas: " << node->unsafe_getData() << " " << other_node->unsafe_getData() << " " << other_other_node->unsafe_getData() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    
    // Some example initialization
    std::shared_ptr<Node<int>> A = std::make_shared<Node<int>>(1);
    std::shared_ptr<Node<int>> B = std::make_shared<Node<int>>(2);
    std::shared_ptr<Node<int>> C = std::make_shared<Node<int>>(3);

    A->addNode(B);
    A->addNode(C);
    B->addNode(A);
    C->addNode(B);

    exploratory_operation(A);

};
```

Releasing locks and calling again *std::lock* is the best approach?

Comment: A possible way is to define a full ordering on the locks and lock them in that order.

Comment: There is no prescribed, standard, authoritative solution  to do something like this, handed out from the mountain, or such. Each case needs to be resolved on its own merits, based on a complete and accurate understanding of how locking works, what causes deadlocks, and how to avoid them. I haven't analyzed the shown code fully, but it does not appear to me that the shown algorithm will not deadlock.

Comment: Can you have one global mutex for the graph (i.e. connections) and the node-local mutex is just for the data? Such that when you iterate through the connections, you just need the global mutex (this should be fast). Then once you find the correct node, you only need the local mutex to get exclusive access to the node data.

Comment: If you don’t modify the data while reading you won’t need a lock.